# Javascript ,comparar o background de uma div pelo DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Bom dia senhores e senhoritas,eu estou fazendo uma comparação para alterar a cor de uma div se ela tiver com um background yellow pra green mas não entendo porque não está dando certo

```
function exerciseTwo() {
    let tagDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(let i = 0; i < tagDiv.length; i += 1) {
            if(tagDiv[i].style.backgroundColor == 'yellow') {
                tagDiv[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      }
    }
}
exerciseTwo();
```

Comment: Gabriel adicione tbm o html na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `element.style` só permite acessar os estilos específicos do element, ou seja, o que estiver dentro do atributo style dele. Utilize o `window.getComputedStyle()` para pegar os estilos aplicados.
No seu código seria:

```
window.getComputedStyle(tagDiv[i]).getPropertyValue('background-color')
```

Comment: muito obrigado!!!!!